# Yii2 - Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The directory is not writable by the Web process

Tags: php, yii2

When I access the site at domain.com/web, I'm displayed this error. I changed the directory permissions and they are listed below. Any solution?

```
PHP User Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/.../site1/web/assets' 

in /var/www/.../site1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php:168
```

Permissions:-

```
root@...:/var/www/.../site1# ls -l web
total 48
drwxrwxr-x 9 root root 4096 Mar 20 15:56 assets
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 20 15:50 css

root@...:/var/www/.../site1/assets# ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 958 Mar 20 17:24 AppAsset.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 628 Mar 20 17:24 error_log
```

Even after running this command:-

`chmod -R 777 .`

```
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 958 Mar 20 17:24 AppAsset.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 628 Mar 20 17:24 error_log
```

I'm still getting same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same issue few days back.

If this was working earlier and suddenly got this error and stopped working than just restart your PC and check again. Else do the following.

In order to make a directory writable by the webserver you have to set the directory's owner or group to Apache's owner or group and enable the write permission for it. Usually, we set the directory to belong to the Apache group and enable the write permission for the group.

This worked for me.

```
chgrp apache /path/to/yourdir
chmod g+w /path/to/yourdir
```

Comment: `chgrp: invalid group: 'apache'`

Comment: This is what I referred to: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/12/09/making-a-directory-writable-by-the-webserver/  And worked in my case. As per that article you can try this: `chmod o+w /path/to/mydir`

Comment: If above didnt worked, than run this command `ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep` - know your group AND than run these commands: `chgrp www-data /path/to/mydir` &  `chmod g+w /path/to/mydir`  . `www-data` is your apache user name. Replace `www-data` (or `apache`) with your user name.  Usually this user is named `apache` or `www-data`.  For more details refer this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58725/how-do-we-know-that-a-directory-is-apache-writable

Comment: @pritis I did, as you said. Yes, it was www-data.  I again ran commands `chgrp www-data .`, `chmod g+w .`, `chmod o+w .`. After doing this, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you just goto that folder, right click and go to `properties` and check `permissions` tab and see who is `owner` & `group` AND compare it with user ur logged in with.

Answer (score 0):

See below:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 958 Mar 20 17:24 AppAsset.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 628 Mar 20 17:24 error_log`

Try setting all the files within that folder to 777 as well.