# Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException The directory is not writable by the Web process?

Tags: php, yii2-basic-app

Invalid Configuration – **yii\base\InvalidConfigException**

The directory is not writable by the Web process:

**/home/liyunfei/NetBeansProjects/my2/duangplat/publicplat/web/assets**

```
1. in /home/liyunfei/NetBeansProjects/my2/duangplat/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php at line 213
204205206207208209210211212213214215216217218219220221222

     * @throws InvalidConfigException if [[basePath]] is invalid
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->basePath = Yii::getAlias($this->basePath);
        if (!is_dir($this->basePath)) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("The directory does not exist: {$this->basePath}");
        } elseif (!is_writable($this->basePath)) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("The directory is not writable by the Web process: {$this->basePath}");
        } else {
            $this->basePath = realpath($this->basePath);
        }
        $this->baseUrl = rtrim(Yii::getAlias($this->baseUrl), '/');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the named asset bundle.
```

Comment: This sounds like a permissions issue to me. What are the permissions to the directory you are getting the error from and what is the end goal(IE when working what should happen?))

Comment: yes!a permissions issue,I changed the directory permissions ,but  
 it doesn't work，it like "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179406/yii2-exception-invalid-configuration-yii-base-invalidconfigexception-with",和他的问题是一样的

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but in case it helps someone:

SELinux (e.g. on Centos 7) is on by default. For my purposes, I just put SELinux in permissive mode and that fixed the issue for me. That said, there is probably a best practice to allow the apache process without going to permissive mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I remove bundled assets folder from web folder.After 1 hour I found it and I created an assets folder in web and it's fixed.